# Related Stack Exchange sites — Sites connexes sur Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, area51

What are the other Stack Exchange sites and proposals *French Language* people might be interested in?

One [site](http://stackexchange.com/sites) or [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals) per answer, unless there are strong thematic connections. And please, vote for the ones you are interested in!

---

Par quels autres sites et propositions de sites Stack Exchange les utilisateurs de *French Language* sont-ils susceptibles d'être intéressés ?

Merci de poster un [site](http://stackexchange.com/sites) ou une [proposition sur Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals) par réponse, sauf connexion thématique forte. Et votez pour ceux qui vous intéressent !

Comment: Should closed propositions still be mentionned ?

Answer (score 12):

### Autres sites de langue / other language sites

Ces sites utilisent comme nous un mélange d'anglais et de la langue étudiée comme métalangues, sauf précision contraire.

- Allemand : [German Language](https://german.stackexchange.com/)
- Anglais langue étrangère : [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)
- Anglais : [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)
- [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/)
- Chinois : [Chinese Language](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/)
- Coréen: [Korean Language](https://korean.stackexchange.com/)
- Espagnol : [Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/)
- Espéranto : [Esperanto Language](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/)
- Italien : [Italian Language](https://italian.stackexchange.com/)
- Japonais : [Japanese Language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/)
- Latin: [Latin Language](https://latin.stackexchange.com/)
- Portugais : [Portuguese Language](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/)
- Russe avec métalangue en russe : [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)
- Russe : [Russian Language](https://russian.stackexchange.com/)
- Ukrainien : [Ukrainian Language](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/)
- [Langues artificielles](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101265/constructed-languages)

### Propositions en phase d'engagement

- (Actuellement, aucune)

### Propositions en phase de définition

- [Arabe](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93710/arabic-language)
- [Catalan](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121280/catalan-language)
- [Hébreu](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102005/hebrew-language)
- [Langues slaves](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102374/slavic-languages)
- [Néerlandais](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/105196/dutch-language)
- [Sanskrit](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109951/sanskrit-language)
- [Swahili](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109910/swahili-language)
- [Tamoul](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96929/tamil-language)

Il y en a peut-être [d'autres](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=language). Chercher dans la catégorie « [Culture](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/3/culture) ».

Comment: I know this breaks the "one site per answer" request, but seriously, I can't be bothered.

Comment: There is a [similar list](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/438/800) on Language Learning Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 10):

### [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)

As of 2011-09-20, the [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) SE has entered public beta. It already has a lot of very interesting content!

Answer (score 4):

### Sites francophones

*[Un moratoire est imposé sur les sites non anglophones.](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-se-2-0-sites-edition)*

Answer (score 4):

### [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/)

> Language Learning Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for students, teachers, polyglots, and anyone interested in the techniques of second-language acquisition.